# Drag Drop behavior not working with Prime faces 3.4

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I recently moved to Prime faces 3.4RC1 from 3.3.1 and noticed that the drag drop behavior stopped working.

I am currently dragging and dropping between 2 different panels. And I have a listener configured to process the drop event :

```
<p:droppable for="testPanel" scope="all">
    <p:ajax listener="#{testController.dropUser}" process="@form"  update="@form"/>
</p:droppable>
```

The dropUser method is not even invoked after I moved to the latest version. I looked around for any outstanding issue related to the drag drop behaviour and could not find one. Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Doesn't answers your question, but, do you need to go back to 3.3.1? 3.4 Final has just been released: http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2160.

Comment: @RinaldoPJr We are already using 3.4RC1 from Maven. Is there a patch on top of this?

Comment: Yes, just "3.4", no "RC1" at the end.

Comment: I tried 3.4 but I still get the problem :-(

Comment: I'd try to go back to 3.4.RC1 and see if it works or not. Maybe it wasn't the PrimeFaces version that caused it to stop working, but some other change made to the code.

Comment: It works on 3.3.1 and the same code does not work on 3.4RC1 or 3.4. I can see that the AJAX call is being made since it goes through my filter but I don't see the backing bean being called.

Comment: I tried with 3.4 and 3.4RC1 but both of them have problems. I can see the request hit the server via my filter but it does not invoke the backing bean method that is associated with the drop event

Comment: Can anyone from the Prime faces development team help?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it working :

Made the following 2 changes :

1. Added an id attribute to the draggable and droppbale components
2. Removed the process attribute.

I think removing the second attribute made it work. But I am still not clear why. I will try to debug further when I get time. But for now I am good.

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar problem when updating to primefaces 4.0.

The [datagrid example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dndGrid.jsf) suggests *handle* and *stack* attributes for the *draggable* tag. 
I was able to solve the problem by removing both of them.